# cannot login with other facebook account socialite in laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite

I have created a facebook developer account but i am able to login through my account that i habve created on facebook if i login with other user i'm not able to login. Is there any settings in facebook developer console.

[image]

[image]

Any solution please

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels

Comment: @CBroe: It is getting stuck `https://subdomain.maindomain.in/auth/facebook/callback?code=46346346346&state=v4346346346` at this url can you please check

Comment: _What_ about this do you think anyone here could "check" ...?